# Authentification and OpLoG ? How to configure mongodb users

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm trying to use the Oplog of a mongodb database.
My software is in Python and use Mongoengine and Pymongo.

It work well if i don't use the **--auth** option, but I wouldlike make it work with authentification.

I go the following error :

```
2017-03-20T13:51:36.721+0100 I ACCESS   [conn13] Unauthorized: not authorized on local to execute command { find: "oplog.$main", filter: {}, sort: { $natural: -1 }, limit: 1, singleBatch: true }
```

For now I have 2 users:

1. mongoDbAdmin (the mongodb administrator user)
2. myAppUsr (the user used in my client application)

I Tried to add an Oplogger user but it still doesn't work.

> db.createUser({user: "oplogger", pwd: "PasswordForOplogger", roles:
>   [{role: "read", db: "local"}]})

I also tried to give to my client user the oplog rights:

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myAppUsr",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "myapp_dev" },
             { role: "readWrite", db: "myapp" },
             { role: "read", db: "local" }]
  }
)
```

I start mongodb with the following command :

> mongod --master --auth

What kind of access should i provide to my user to allow him to read the OpLog ?

My connection using mongoengine :

```
    mongo_client = connect(
        db="myapp_dev",
        username="myAppUsr",
        password="password",
        host="my.server.ip.adress",
        port=27017,
        authentication_source="myapp_dev",
        socketTimeoutMS=5000,
        connectTimeoutMS=5000,
        serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000)
```

Authentification log :

> I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 192.168.1.xx:60264 #1 (1
>   connection now open)
>
> I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 192.168.1.xx:60264
>   conn1: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.4.0" }, os: { type:
>   "Windows", name: "Windows 10", architecture: "AMD64", version:
>   "10.0.14393-SP0" }, platform: "CPython 3.5.3.final.0" }
>
> I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 192.168.1.xx:60266 #2 (2
>   connections now open)
>
> I NETWORK  [conn2] received client metadata from 192.168.1.xx:60266
>   conn2: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.4.0" }, os: { type:
>   "Windows", name: "Windows 10", architecture: "AMD64", version:
>   "10.0.14393-SP0" }, platform: "CPython 3.5.3.final.0" }
>
> I ACCESS   [conn2] Unauthorized: not authorized on local to execute
>   command { find: "oplog.$main", filter: {}, sort: { $natural: -1 },
>   limit: 1, singleBatch: true }
>
> I ACCESS   [conn2] Successfully authenticated as principal myappUsr on
>   myapp_dev

Comment: How does your connection Uri looks like ? You have to username, password and auth db before making any calls.

Comment: I don't use Uri style connection, i use the mongoengine connect method. I updated my question with my connect method

Comment: Can you try adding `authentication_source` and set it to the dbname where username that you are using is created ?

Comment: I just tried, using my db and the admin, same error.

Comment: What mongo server version are you on ? Can you try `myAppUsr` with password and db as `local` for `authentication_source` ?

Comment: I'm using mongo version 3.4.2. I was already with myAppUsr in my connect method (i updated my question with the hardcoded values, it will me more explicit). If i use 'local' as authentification_source, i have an authentification error

Comment: Thank you for details. You dont have to create any specific user for accessing oplog. Your normal db user should be able to access. Looks like you have everything you need in your connection method. Make sure your authentication work first checking in mongo console.

Comment: The authentification seem to work (i posted the log). At least I'm able to vizualize and edit my data, but don't reveice any notification when i update a document from the database